# application with google maps library presents imperfections on google play

Tags: reactjs, expo

I published an application on the platform and as soon as it was approved it started to have imperfections in the part where we implemented Google Maps, how can I solve this imperfection caused by the platform?

I'm using react native for development along with Expo.

Comment: To achieve your specific requirement, it would be helpful to provide more context and detail about your project. By providing a more comprehensive description of your situation, you'll receive more accurate and detailed answers that are better suited to your needs.